# Cloudinary storage issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, ecmascript-6

When using Clodinary in my app like this

```
const storage = cloudinaryStorage({
cloudinary: cloudinary,
folder: "demo",
allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png"],
transformation: [{ width: 500, height: 500, crop: "limit" }]
});
```

it says cloudinaryStorage is not a function

and i did some googling to this issue and found this

```
const storage = new cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: async (req, file) => {
    return {
      folder: 'folder_name',
      format: 'jpeg',
      public_id: 'some_unique_id',
    };
  },
});
```

it says that cloudinaryStorage is not a constructor

what should i do to solve this

Comment: Why is `python` a tag here?

Answer (score 0):

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');

const storage =  new CloudinaryStorage({
cloudinary: cloudinary,
folder: "demo",
allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png"],
transformation: [{ width: 500, height: 500, crop: "limit" }]
});
```